# jQuery refer to files in folders

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic, tabs

```
$(function () {
    $(".links2lvl a").click(function () {
        var page = this.hash.substr(1); /*in case of first link - works*/
        /* var page = this.hash.substr(7);  in case of second link - nope.jpg*/
        $.get(page + ".php", function (gotHTML) {
            $("#content").html(gotHTML);
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<section class="tabs">
    <ul class="links1lvl">
        <li><a>About</a>
            <ul class="links2lvl">
                <li><a href="#who">Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="about/#personal">Personal</a></li>
```

So here I have two two sets of code. First is jQuery function, which extracts given PHP file and it's contents are shown in div with `id="content"`.

The other is my 2 level list. In the second level you can see pages I'm trying refer to. The first link works just fine, jQuery successfully extracts the content and shows it given plave, but the second link in the `folder about/` thats another story, the function doesn't seem to find it. The question is, how do I refer to .whatever from another file?

Comment: Why don't you just use something like `data-page="somefolder/mypage"` instead of dealing with hashes and stuff? Then you get `page = $(this).data('page')` et voilà

Comment: This appeared as a nice solution at the beginning because I had only a couple of pages - no need to make folders. Now I have 20+ something pages and that would be a mess. However, I can use yours, but I still need to know, why this solution doesn't work, so I understand the problem.

Comment: Well, putting hashes in a path is a strange idea. Hash is not part of an URL, it just allows to add stuff _after_ the URL. Besides, I don't get why you think this will solve your multiple files problem, and the classic `data-page` solution won't.

Comment: I'm not saying `data-page` won't solve the problem. The hash worked just fine when I had all the files in one folder. After I added other folders, I tried to modify it by increasing `substr()` number, so jQuery could still reach that file but for some reason it can't. Whatever the reason, thanks for advise, going with  `data-page` now.

Comment: Yeah, but my point is, why _add_ a slash in the first place? It's absolutely useless, and only adds complexity. This hash comes from nowhere and has no reason to be. Just get rid of it and your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the problems I see in code are based on attempts to solve challenges by adding more challenges to the code. :)

I would give a suggestion and I hope you don't mind: I would solve it by adding a "**data-***" to each **a** tag to hold the reference you need to find using **this.hash** (or, maybe, use **.each** or **.map**) to loop through the elements and extract the proper URL to be used).

What happen is, **this.hash** will return "#who", but it is also a valid ID selector in jQuery ([see more here](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)). Hence **this.hash** will find "#who", but won't find "about/#personal" (because the hash element is not the first character of the string).

You could use **string.split('#')** to capture the string straight after the "#", then save it in - for instance -, the **data-hash** parameter at each **a** tag while constructing the HTML. Then it should be fairly easy to obtain the content needed for your application (once again, it is always about how to minimize challenges, instead of add them). ;)

Sadly I am no able to build a code sample now, but if you have difficulties following this idea, contact me and I will write a quick sample code for you.

Comment: Yeah that's pretty much what I'm saying in the comments above :)

Comment: When I start writing the answer there was no comments yet. When it was posted there were three comments, though. :)  Sadly I can only post answers until I reach 50 points, then I will be able to comment. :(

Comment: This is great! :) I can see the problem now. Also, no need for the code, I need to come up with proper code on my own, so I can learn from it. But thank you so much for showing me the problem and the way how to solve it. :)